# Making div look like input: cross-browser compatability, not rendering in chrome

Tags: css, cross-browser

**TOPIC:**
I'm making a couple div's to accept some drag/drop values and stylizing them to look like inputs.
Everything renders beautifully in Firefox.
In Chrome, however, the borders and box-shadows are not rendering correctly. (I'm in Chm v.24, btw)

**GOAL:**
Above all else, I just want it to work.
But ... I'm just as happy to get *any* suggestions on how I can do *anything* better  :)

**NOTE:**
This is for an intra-office app. FireFox & Chrome are the only two browsers officially supported here, so, while compatibility across *all* browsers would definitely be nice, I am only required to code to those two.

**CODE:** [Also visible ***here on jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/mOrloff/6qbwY/)

```
/** html **/
<section id="dragged-drop-zone" >
    <div class="look-like-input textfield" contenteditable></div>
    <br />
    <div class="look-like-input textarea" contenteditable></div>
</section>
```

.

```
/** css **/
.look-like-input{
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
    min-height: 1.5em;
}
.look-like-input.textfield{
    appearance: field;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}
.look-like-input.textarea{
    appearance: field;
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: both;
    min-height: 3.5em;
}
.look-like-input:focus{
    border: 1px solid #69F;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 100, 255, 0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 100, 255, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 100, 255, 0.15);
}


#dragged-drop-zone{
    border: 1px solid #666;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

Thanks-a-bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have so far that works

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #dragged-drop-zone {
            border: 1px solid #666;
            -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
            -moz-border-radius: 1em;
            border-radius: 1em;
            padding: 1em;
        }

        .myinput {
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
            padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
            min-height: 1.5em;
        }

        .myinput:focus {
            border: 1px solid #69F;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 100, 255, 0.15);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 100, 255, 0.15);
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 100, 255, 0.15);
        }

        .mytextfield {
            appearance: field;
            -moz-appearance: textfield;
            -webkit-appearance: field;
        }

        .mytextarea {
            appearance: field;
            -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
            -webkit-appearance: area;
            overflow: auto;
            resize: both;
            min-height: 3.5em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="dragged-drop-zone" >
        <div class="myinput mytextfield" contenteditable></div>
        <br />
        <div class="myinput mytextarea" contenteditable></div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's your:

```
-webkit-appearance:
```

Which the purpose is to have it look like a textbox input or textarea

Just add this and see what I mean:

```
.look-like-input {
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
min-height: 1.5em;
-webkit-appearance: none !important;
}
```

Mentioned here:

[Removing rounded corners from a <select> element in Chrome/Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780109/removing-rounded-corners-from-a-select-element-in-chrome-webkit)

If appereace is crucial yes check **Kevin Brydon** method.

Comment: It was tough to pick the "answer" between this and Kevin's post. While Kevin's spoke directly to the goal in my OP, **this** is the **answer** to the _cause_ of my problem. Thanks-a-bunch for the help. Much appreciated.