# HTML Input text side by side

Tags: html, css

i've been trying to figure out how to make the input text and input button side by side. Not only that, it seems my `text-align : center` is not applying for the text input.

I'm trying not to add multiple spaces just to indent the placeholder.

I've been trying various way but i'm still stuck :
Codepen :-

https://codepen.io/jayvicious/pen/dRyJKE
HTML :

```
<div class="cell at-bottom">
      <input type="text" placeholder="All Japan Cities" class="formElement">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Check In Date" class="formElement">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Check Out Date" class="formElement">
      <select name="cars">
  <option value="Guest1">1 Guest</option>
  <option value="Guest2">2 Guest</option>
  <option value="Guest3">3 Guest</option>
  <option value="Guest4">4 Guest</option>
  <option value="Guest5">5 Guest</option>
</select>
      <input type="submit" value="Search" class="formElement">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=text], select {
text-allign:center;  
padding: 12px 20px;
margin: auto;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid  #000000;

}

input[type=submit] {
    font-family: 'arial', sans-serif;
    background-color:white;
    text-align: center;
    color:red;
  padding: 14px 45px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: 1px solid  #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cell.at-bottom {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

My expected output should be something like this :
[image]

EDIT : Center issue has been fixed by matthias gwiozda
Link that fixed it : [Center HTML Input Text Field Placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381446/center-html-input-text-field-placeholder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your placeholder problem was that you spelt `text-align` as `text-allign`. You don't need WebKit integration if you want to style all the text to the center. If you want to center just the `placeholder` then you will have to use WebKit integration.

For your spacing problem, try adding this block to your css:

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><path fill='#444' d='M7.406 7.828l4.594 4.594 4.594-4.594 1.406 1.406-6 6-6-6z'></path></svg>");
    background-position: 100% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

(`select` styling taken from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37462242/3088508))

Another thing I did to fix the spacing was to put all the inputs into a `table`, this seemed to fix it.

```css
input[type=text],
select {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

input[type=submit] {
  font-family: 'arial', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  padding: 12.5px 45px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cell.at-bottom {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.cell.at-bottom td {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><path fill='#444' d='M7.406 7.828l4.594 4.594 4.594-4.594 1.406 1.406-6 6-6-6z'></path></svg>");
  background-position: 100% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<table class="cell at-bottom"><tr><td><input type="text" placeholder="All Japan Cities" class="formElement"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="Check In Date" class="formElement"></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="Check Out Date" class="formElement"></td><td><select name="cars">
  <option value="Guest1">1 Guest</option>
  <option value="Guest2">2 Guest</option>
  <option value="Guest3">3 Guest</option>
  <option value="Guest4">4 Guest</option>
  <option value="Guest5">5 Guest</option>
</select></td><td><input type="submit" value="Search" class="formElement"></tr></table>
```

Comment: Somehow i feel so embarrass now lol. Checking without posting. Thanks for pointing that out. So it's not a must? Let me remove my edit.

Comment: @FreedomPride Yes it's not a must if you want _all_ the text to be center aligned, however, if you only want the _placeholder text_ to be center aligned you will need WebKit integrations.

Comment: It's just the spelling when i posted here but the code uses text-align same goes in the codepen

Comment: Didn't see the type-mistake. So this is the better Answer for the Placeholder problem :)  . For the spacing - problem you can check my edited Post i hope it helps

Comment: @FreedomPride I've updated my answer for your spacing problem, can you check if it works?

Comment: No luck bro, here's the code : https://codepen.io/jayvicious/pen/dRyJKE

Comment: Forget my answer with the display table. It is working, but only for Google Chrome Browsers. Firefox is displaying the display: inline-table with spaces as well.

Comment: Is there webkit for general one? Yeah, i had that same problem on safari and chrome thou.

Comment: @FreedomPride I put each of the inputs into a table, that seemed to fix it. Any luck this time? (And yes there has to be no spaces between each of the inputs, otherwise more spacing shows up)

Comment: I tried table for my current design it will introduce a lot of displacement so i did few div to act as an table. Here's the full : https://codepen.io/jayvicious/pen/dRyJKE

Comment: Erh, i think you need to save it cause you can't overwrite my codepen

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of [Center HTML Input Text Field Placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381446/center-html-input-text-field-placeholder) .

As David mentioned, you can fix the type-mistake with "text-allign" or if you want to give only your placeholders the Text-align you can use this:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align: center;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align: center;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align: center; 
}
```

Edit:
The following solution is only working for Chroium Browsers. So its useless:

<strike>For you spacing - problem you can set the following Css for your Container of your Input-fields :</strike>

```
.cell.at-bottom    {
display: inline-table;
}
```

Comment: So it has to be in a separate CSS? I've tried , it work. I'll upvote for it cause i never gotten that page from my google search. So i need to integrate it with webkit?

Comment: you should use not only the webkit - Version. If you want all Browsers to show the same styles then you should implement all of them

Comment: Is there any other way not to change the css for the cell at bottom cause i've the middle part and bottom part. Upon i put it, it goes haywire.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to your HTML and CSS that should do the trick. e.g.:

HTML:

```
<div class="cell at-bottom">
      <input type="text" placeholder="All Japan Cities" class="formElement">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Check In Date" class="formElement">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Check Out Date" class="formElement">
      <select name="cars" class="formElement">
  <option value="Guest1">1 Guest</option>
  <option value="Guest2">2 Guest</option>
  <option value="Guest3">3 Guest</option>
  <option value="Guest4">4 Guest</option>
  <option value="Guest5">5 Guest</option>
</select>
      <input type="submit" value="Search" class="formElement">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.cell{
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.formElement{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 46px;
  border: 1px solid  #000000;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 100px;
}

input[type=submit] {
    font-family: 'arial', sans-serif;
    background-color:white;
    color:red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cell.at-bottom {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

The key change is to use display: flex for your div container. From there I grouped all input and select elements in the .formElement and sized them in there. This keeps everything the same width, height, and in line.

Comment: First time i'm actually listening about flex in this situation . No luck mate : https://codepen.io/jayvicious/pen/dRyJKE

Comment: It seems that its working? I see all the elements side by side and the placeholder text in the center. Is there a separate issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: This is literally the full code . I tried to inherit flex : this what happens : https://codepen.io/jayvicious/pen/dRyJKE

Comment: With your full code you have several things going on that need to be modified, but flex can solve is something that can save you a lot of time in the future once you get the hang of it. This is a great synopsis of flex: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ to get you started