# Rounded corners causing styling issue for select box on IOS devices

Tags: ios, css, iphone, select

The select box i use to "sort products" on our wordpress website is causing some styling issues on IOS devices.

I want the select box to have a rounded corners. It does this on IOS but it shows the edges of its default styles and `overflow:hidden` is not working

[image]

How do i remove the corners?

```
select {
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 40px;
    text-indent: 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 0;
}

  <select name="orderby" class="orderby"><option value="popularity">Sort by popularity</option><option value="rating">Sort by average rating</option><option value="date">Sort by newness</option><option value="price">Sort by price: low to high</option><option value="price-desc">Sort by price: high to low</option><option value="alphabetical">Sort by name: A to Z</option><option value="reverse_alpha">Sort by name: Z to A</option><option value="on_sale_first">Show sale items first</option><option value="random_list" selected="selected">Random</option> </select>
```

Comment: by iOS you mean chrome on iOS or Safari?

Comment: @Alex, I did include the html and css...

Comment: tinyurl.com/y93x79hq here is a link to the category with the sort option top right of content.

Comment: only solution i see atm, is set -webkit-appearance: none and add box arrows by image:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780109/removing-rounded-corners-from-a-select-element-in-chrome-webkit#answer-37462242

Answer (score 1):

iOS devices do not seem to support border-radius of more than 10px. So you can either make your border-radius 10px for all devices or you can target Safari on ios devices like below:

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
    /* ios device specific */
    select, select.form-control {
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
}
```

If you do want to have 40px of border-radius on iOS devices as well, then you can remove the background altogether and then use a custom arrow image (as this will also remove the arrow)

```
select, select.form-control {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><path fill='%23444' d='M7.406 7.828l4.594 4.594 4.594-4.594 1.406 1.406-6 6-6-6z'></path></svg>");
        background-position: 100% 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```