# iOS Select Rounded Corners Background Color

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I am having a display problem on iOS with both Safari and Firefox.  I have rounded corners to my input fields (text and selects) that are not being displayed correctly.  Under Firefox on a Windows and Android device they display properly.

Specifically the select field under iOS has the outside of the rounded corner a different color than the background color of the form the control is on.  I can make it disappear by adding the following to the CSS `-webkit-appearance: none;` but then the drop down arrow disappears also.

I’m not sure what to target to turn the little bits of extra corners to the form’s background color `background-color: #E0E0E0;`

Any help would be appreciated.  My CSS contains the following

```
select
{
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[image]

With `-webkit-appearance: none;`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me.

Select option with an arrow img:

```css
.select-css {
 display: block;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #444;
 line-height: 1.3;
 padding: .6em 1.4em .5em .8em;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 border: 1px solid #aaa;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.04);
 border-radius: .5em;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
 background-color: #fff;
 background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23007CB2%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E'),
   linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
 background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
 background-position: right .7em top 50%, 0 0;
 background-size: .65em auto, 100%;
}
```

```html
<select class="select-css">
 <option>This is a native select element</option>
 <option>Apples</option>
 <option>Bananas</option>
 <option>Grapes</option>
 <option>Oranges</option>
</select>
```

Important part is this

```
.select-css {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Reference: [Removing rounded corners from a <select> element in Chrome/Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780109/removing-rounded-corners-from-a-select-element-in-chrome-webkit#answer-37462242)

Detailed fix: https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/select-css.html

Comment: That removes the extra background bits but also removes the down arrow for the select.  See new image.

Comment: @glez This is an issue with iOS. So you can add arrow img into the field. Try the link.